# URL Session Data Structure

Tags: swift, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am building iOS app where I insert an input string and search this string using Google , then I get the data string back and use it to search for specific word or series of characters

I use URLSessionDataTask to do this

```
let baseURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=~+%22education%22%20-intitle:%22profiles%22%20-inurl:%22dir/+%22+site:ca.linkedin.com/in/+OR+site:ca.linkedin.com/pub/" 

if let url = URL(string: baseURL) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .ascii)
                    
                    let decodedString = dataString?.utf8
                    
                    print(dataString)
                }
                
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

the problem is that the dataString I got back is very strange and I cant deal with it , so how can I get it as normal string so every thing is clear enough ???

```
if let url = URL(string: baseURL) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .ascii)
                    
                    let decodedString = dataString?.utf8
                    
                    print(dataString)
                }
                
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: .utf8 instead of .ascii perhaps

Comment: Joakim's guess of using .utf8 seems like a good bet. You will need to edit your question to tell us what you are expecting and what you're getting if you want more specific help.

Comment: I've tried .utf8 but got the same problem , I want the text shown on google page to be clear so I can extract the text I want inside the app

Comment: "the problem is that the dataString I got back is very strange and I cant deal with it " You get a HTML page... It starts with "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=", what did you expect?